# RewriteRule and php get variables

Tags: php, .htaccess, get, url-rewriting

Here is my challenge.

My www.mysite.com/lab/brand/folder/modify.php page has a flash app that get a variable from the url for example www.mysite.com/lab/brand/folder/modify.php?id=1234  The flash app pulls the 1234 as the id and there are a ton of files located in the folders near that app that I can't move and keep the app working correctly.

I tried the following but the app doesn't pull in the get variable. It does rewrite the url but the flash app doesn't seem to get the variable.

^lab/modify/([0-9]+)/?$ lab/brand/folder/modify.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]

I'd be happy with the rewriten url to look like www.mysite.com/lab/modify.php?id=1234 if that would work for get get variable but I don't know how to write this.  I tried the following but that didn't work so I know I'm writing this wrong.

^lab/modify.php?id=([0-9]+)/?$ lab/brand/folder/modify.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
LP

Answer (score 1):

It's just as simple as:

```
RewriteRule ^lab/modify/$ lab/brand/folder/modify.php [QSA]
```

the `QSA` flag (Query String Append) will add your GET variables for any URL Like:

```
www.mysite.com/lab/modify/?id=1234
```

You can get variable with: `$_GET['id']`

Comment: add it with `RewriteRule ^lab/modify/$ lab/brand/folder/modify.php [QSA]` like above, and that `{QUERY_STRING}` will be gone